# Trigger specific AWS Codepipeline source stage when change is made to a specific directory in repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, terraform, aws-codepipeline

I have a number of services in a single GitHub repository, each service has its own CodePipeline on AWS managed through Terraform. Instead of triggering all of the pipelines on commit, I'd like to know how I can trigger each service's pipeline if its directory had any changes on commit, without having to split the services each into its own repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being simpler than I had anticipated, there are github actions that do exactly what I needed.

[This action](https://github.com/MarceloPrado/has-changed-path) checks whether a path had a change, and [this action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/aws-codepipeline-trigger) triggers a specific pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that there's a conditional source stage support per folder at code pipeline as we speak. Just finished checking this documentation about [sources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-reference-CodeCommit.html) in CodePipeline. It does not seem to contain a folder-level filtering.

You could try this [CDK-based template](https://github.com/aws-samples/monorepo-multi-pipeline-trigger) solution which showcases a mono-repository, which is composed of multiple services, have different CI/CD pipelines for each service. The solution detects which top level directory the modification happened and triggers the AWS CodePipeline configured to that directory.

This is sad but they might add it in the future. I've also wanted Quality gates, images from readme files in code-commit but these features seem too hard to implement haha.

Comment: Perhaps not CDK itself, but the lambda idea is good enough, I can have a GitHub webhook trigger the lambda, and then the lambda triggers the relevant pipeline

Comment: Glad it helped man! Terrraform or other ways of provisioning are not a bad idea to be honest!

Answer (score 1):

Create GitHub workflow under actions with the following yaml file:

```
name: Conditional Deploy

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
    paths:
      - 'ENTER_YOUR_DIRECTORY/**'

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Trigger AWS CodePipeline
        uses: zulhfreelancer/aws-codepipeline-action@v1.0.7
        with:
          aws-region: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
          aws-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_PIPELINE_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-secret-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_PIPELINE_SECRET_KEY }}
          pipeline-name: ${{ secrets.AWS_PIPELINE_NAME }}
```

Create 4 secrets (`AWS_REGION`, `AWS_PIPELINE_ACCESS_KEY`, `AWS_PIPELINE_SECRET_KEY`, `AWS_PIPELINE_NAME`) in Github. You can check [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository) on how to create secrets. Change `ENTER_YOUR_DIRECTORY` to your directory name. On change in your directory, it will trigger the aws code pipeline.

I spend more than a couple of hours to figure this out.

Hope this helps and saves some time for you.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will help monorepo-based application in AWS CodeCommit. With this approach each app/microservice in your monorepo-based application can have a dedicated CI/CD pipeline which will **detect changes in relevant app directory!**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/automatically-detect-changes-and-initiate-different-codepipeline-pipelines-for-a-monorepo-in-codecommit.html

AWS Sample code - https://github.com/aws-samples/monorepo-multi-pipeline-trigger